# detect stack corruption

Tags: c++, windbg

Sometimes some code portion in my application corrupts the stack. But the problem will be visible only after some time. So we cannot identify the exact location of the problem. Is there any tools available to detect stack corruption in a c++ application immediately after corrupting the stack?

Is there any windbg tools to identify this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compile with `/RTCs`, which enables stack frame run-time error checking.  See [/RTC (Run-Time Error Checks)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wtf2dfz%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Is it possible to use /RTCs in release build?

Comment: disabling optimization is enough for using /RTC in release ?

Answer (score 0):

Does the corruption always happen in the same place?  If so, you can easily use your debugger to set a watchpoint to detect writes at that location and see who's doing the corruption.  Sometimes analyzing the data that corrupted the stack can also help you out - if it's a string, for example, you might be able to narrow down the code that's writing it.